# Trying to install but getting an error "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password)"

Tags: docker, ssh, ibm-cloud-private

I am able to connect to the other nodes with SSH without a password. I have      followed the IBM KC instructions. Here is the command and results:

```
ubuntu@ipc1:/opt/ibm-cloud-private-ce-3.1.0/cluster$ sudo docker run --net=host -t -e LICENSE=accept -v "$(pwd)":/installer/cluster ibmcom/icp-inception:3.1.0 install
 PLAY [Checking Python interpreter] *********************************************
 TASK [Checking Python interpreter] *********************************************
 fatal: [172.31.39.234]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).
unreachable: true
     fatal: [172.31.39.53]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password)

unreachable: true
fatal: [172.31.44.240]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: ed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied           (publickey,password).
       unreachable: true
     NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
     NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
     PLAY RECAP      *********************************************************************
     172.31.39.234              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
     172.31.39.53               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
     172.31.44.240              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0

 Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you ssh between hosts without specifiy any password?

Any by using `sudo` that mean you are trying to ssh passwordless via root.

So I think you haven't copy the root ssh key between your hosts.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because you have not generated the ***password less authentication*** within the same server(self ssh).

Follow these steps and you will be able to get rid of the issue specified above.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh-keygen
```

**Sample Output:**
[image]

**Then run the following commands:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys                                            
[root@localhost ~]# chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys                                        
[root@localhost ~]# cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys                          
[root@localhost ~]# cd /opt/ibm-cloud-private-ce-3.1.0/cluster/                                 
[root@localhost ~]# cp -rp ~/.ssh/id_rsa ./ssh_key
```

Also make sure that hostname is mapped to the host's IP address in the local `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you install an IBM Cloud Private cluster, you must configure authentication between configuration nodes. You can generate an SSH key pair on your boot node and share that key with the other cluster nodes. To share the key with the cluster nodes, you must have the access to an account with root access for each node in your cluster.

Follow the ICP 3.1.0 Knowledge Center (KC) steps here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.1.0/installing/ssh_keys.html